# How to make checked button at BottomNavigationMenu?

Tags: android

I need to find a way to make any other BottomNavigationMenu button checked but not the first when an activity just opened.

I've read through plenty of docs and searched in google and see that to reach my goal I should use *android:checked="true"* in my menu items file. But it do not work in my case.

Here is my **bottom_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/appointments_button"
        android:title="@string/appointment_menu_link"
        android:icon="@drawable/calendar_white"
        android:checked="false"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/booking_button"
        android:title="@string/booking_menu_link"
        android:icon="@drawable/plus_white"
        android:checked="true"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/user_account"
        android:title="@string/profile_menu_link"
        android:icon="@drawable/user_account"
        android:checked="false"/>
</menu>
```

Below my activity file **employee_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".BarbersActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="56dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:fontFamily="roboto-medium"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_masters"
                    android:textColor="#D9000000"
                    android:textFontWeight="500"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/primary_dark_color"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_black_icon_color"
                app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_black_text_color">
            </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also I added *api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'* to my build.gradle dependencies.

Please advice if it's even possible to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can only be done by code. Try out this:
After calling `bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(...)`, add the following line of code:

`bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.booking_button);`

Or alternatively:
`bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.booking_button).setChecked(true);`

This should select the desired menu item inside the BottomNavigationBar.